# Combining two layer symbologies into single legend item using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, print-composer, legend

In QGIS 2.18.13 on Windows 10, I have symbolized a polygon with two layers on top of either other; the bottom layer is a solid fill color, and the top layer is a BDiagonal (hash).  The two layers together produce a colored polygon with a hashed overlay in the map.

In the print composer, is there a way to combine the two legend entries that result from these two layers into a single element, such that the symbol for that polygon is shown as a single colored box with the hashing over top of it?

Right now I just have the two separate layers with their separate symbology.  I need them combined.

Alternatively, maybe there is a way to produce this same symbology in a single layer on the map prior to the composer, so that this isn't an issue.  I just haven't found a way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick tip for legend organisation problems : I usually use memory layers and organize them as I wish.

- Add a memory virtual layer (with no geometry)
- Make the symbology you want
- activate the memory layer by ticking the box
- add to print composer

You can create completelly fake layers and add them to the legend object. Very useful when you want to have a firm grip on your legend elements and for customized legends.

Example :

- First add your real layers :

[image: memory fake layer]

- Then add a memory layer and use "categorized" style for example to create as many category as you like. Here, i added the 2 layers symbology and added a third one out of thin air :) Don(t care about the value column, here it's useless.

[image: memory layer classified]

- Finally add this memory layer to your legend :

[image: add memory layer to legend]

You now master your legend !

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I figured out a different way to approach this...

Answer (score 4):

I figured out a simple way to do this.  Just add a Layer Symbol from within the Single Symbol Layer Styling dialog.

[image]

This wasn't obvious before, but is exactly what I needed!